# If I don't use in tableview, download function work,If i use it crash

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I have a problem with observing data from firebase, basically I have 2 observers which observe data from Firebase.
 I'm retrieving 2 type of dictionaries, users and posts.
 The post one working correctly, But the user one does not working.
 When I don't use in tableview the users one is working correctly. 
Here is the post one :

```
    func downloadFirebasePostData(){
    DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child(selectedTeamEnglish).child(postId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value,with: { (snapshot) in
        print("azat: entered in downloadfirebase post number \(snapshot.childrenCount)")

        if let postDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>{
            print("azat:entered in postdict")
            let post = Post(postKey: self.postId, postData: postDict)
            print("AZAT: POSTDICT in post \(postDict["like"])")

            self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
        }
        print("AZAT: Post count in postvc \(self.posts.count)")
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
}
```

The downloadFirebasePostData() is working fine, and i can use it in tableView. And here is the users one:

```
func downloadUserData(){
    if let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser{
        print("AZAT: download user data id \(currentUser.uid))")

        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            print("AZAT: userdict is \(snapshot.value)")
            if let userDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>{
                print("AZAT: userdict is \(snapshot.value)")
                let user = User(userData: userDict)
                self.users.insert(user, at: 0)
                print("AZAT: user count\(self.users.count)")

            }
           self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

    }
}
```

The downloadUserData() function is not working.
 I can't even see the print line on console.

```
print("AZAT: userdict is \(snapshot.value)")
```

I tried to not use in tableView the users array, and The downloadUserData() function worked fine.
 I saw the dictionary on console. The tableView section is :

```
 if indexPath.section == 0 {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as! PostCell
            cell.likeButton.tag = 0
            cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostVC.postLikePressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.dislikeButton.tag = 0
            cell.dislikeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostVC.postDislikedPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            print("AZAT: fillcell in dequeu section 0")
        if let img = PostVC.imageCache.object(forKey: users[0].profilePhoto as NSString){
            cell.fillCell(post: posts[0],img: img,user: users[0])
            return cell
        }else{
            cell.fillCell(post: posts[0],img: nil,user: users[0])
            return cell
        }
```

So the basically I download data, put it in arrays, and update UI in tableView. In the console it says "fatal error: Index out of range
". Because the users array has nothing in it.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: You question states that the code crashes but it doesn't say where. Can you update your question with more information about the crash?

Comment: Also, in the dowloadUserData() function is it printing "AZAT: download user data id"?

Comment: Please update your question with more information per my above comments so we can provide a solution.

Comment: Yes it is printing "AZAT: download user data id". But it doesn't print "AZAT: userdict is \(snapshot.value)" , i updated with more data. If you would like, i can send project to you. Its on github@Jay

Comment: Post the link and I'll take a look.

Comment: https://github.com/azatgoktas/taraftar @Jay

Comment: jay@j.com password: 123456 after you logged in click on 'besiktas'. When you clicked on a post, it is going to crash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126407/discussion-between-jay-and-azat).